# If all of the sequences in $U$ are not convergent, is $U$ closed?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, proof-verification

We know that in a Banach space $X$, a subset $U$ of $X$ is closed iff the limit of every convergent sequence in $U$ is also in $U$. Therefore, if all of the sequences in $U$ are not convergent, then $U$ is closed. Is that true?

Actually, I am trying to prove $U=\{(1+1/n)e_n\}$ is closed, because every sequence in $U$ is divergent, where $\{e_n\}$ is an orthonormal sequence in an infinite dimensional Hilbert space $X$.

Or is there any other proof of this fact?

Comment: Constant sequences are convergent.

Comment: The only space in which all sequences are divergent is the empty set, which is closed. So, while your statement is true, it won't help you for that example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initial thoughts are technically correct but not the way to go to solve your questions. Rather, consider a sequence $\{x_n\}\subset U$ with $x_n\rightarrow p$ and $p\notin U$.

Then there is an $N$ with $x_N\neq p$ and $\|x_N-p\| < \frac{1}{3}$. Further there is a $K$ such that $\|x_K-p\| < \|x_N-p\| < 1/3.$ This implies $\|x_N-x_K\|< \frac{2}{3}$.

Finally show that this last inequality is not possible for elements of $U$ to get a contradiction.